# How to keep running selenium and go back

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I have this code which tries multiple phone numbers on Yahoo, now what I realized is that every time the phone number is working or is registered in Yahoo I get captcha, I want to edit this code in a way that if captcha come it goes back and saves this number to a file and continues checking numbers. after trying for long time i see if i try multiple time then comes this and it can be skipped if just press the button "try over again" but if number exist in yahoo then it gives captcha.
[image]

But if number exist then this comes

[image]

So easily explained. Code which checks Yahoo user by phone number and if it exist the site gives captcha usually I don't know if it gives after the first one, if captcha comes then goes back and keeps checking and saves the phone number to a file or a list.

This is my code

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import selenium
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
import contextlib as textmanager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
PATH= "C:\chromedrivers\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

list=[]
file= open("numbers.txt", "r")

for line in file:
        line = line.strip()   #Saving phone numbers to a list
        list.append(line)






driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/")



element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='consent-page']/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button")))

element.click();

time.sleep(1)

sign_in= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ybar-inner-wrap']/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/a").click()
time.sleep(1)
forgot_phone= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mbr-forgot-link']").click()

time.sleep(2)
inputt= driver.find_element_by_id("username")
time.sleep(2)
buttonn= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='yid-challenge']/form/div[2]/button")

counter=0

nonumber= open("nonumber.txt","w")

while counter != len(list):
    inputt= driver.find_element_by_id("username")                                                  #here i am trying to put phone numebrs and check but capcha coming
    buttonn= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button")

    inputt.send_keys(list[counter])
    time.sleep(1)
    buttonn.click()
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p[data-error]")) > 0 :
        inputt= driver.find_element_by_id("username")
        inputt.clear()
        nonumber.write(list[counter])
        nonumber.close()
    counter=counter+1
```

Comment: Are you trying to hack people's Yahoo! accounts?

Comment: dude no !  i just have a client who wants check which phone numbers have yahoo accounts . So if hacking is happening its not me.

Comment: That doesn't really make me feel any better about this...